# Flutter - How to implement inline editing?

Tags: flutter

I found a similar behaviour on Safari:

[image]

Comment: In the video you have uploaded there are lots of things included can you please clear what you really want 
I am not getting the inline editing thing!

Comment: Double click "text" to edit it in place is inline editing means.  @ᴅᴇʙᴊᴇᴇᴛ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the correct answer:

```dart
class InlineEditableText extends StatefulWidget {
  const InlineEditableText({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.style,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String text;
  final TextStyle style;

  @override
  State<InlineEditableText> createState() => _InlineEditableTextState();
}

class _InlineEditableTextState extends State<InlineEditableText> {
  var _isEditing = false;
  final _focusNode = FocusNode();
  late String _text = widget.text;
  late final TextStyle _style = widget.style;
  late TextEditingController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = TextEditingController(text: _text);
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() => _isEditing = false);
      } else {
        _controller.selection = TextSelection(
          baseOffset: 0,
          extentOffset: _controller.value.text.runes.length,
        );
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _focusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () => setState(() {
        _isEditing = !_isEditing;
        _focusNode.requestFocus();
      }),
      child: TextField(
        maxLines: 1,
        style: _style,
        focusNode: _focusNode,
        controller: _controller,
        onSubmitted: (changed) {
          setState(() {
            _text = changed;
            _isEditing = false;
          });
        },
        showCursor: _isEditing,
        cursorColor: Colors.black,
        enableInteractiveSelection: _isEditing,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          isDense: true,
          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 0,
            vertical: 4.4,
          ),
          border: _isEditing
              ? const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0)),
                )
              : InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: answer]

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is that on tap of normal text, the text field should be editable and we can able to edit the text.

[Have an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LQ0Y.jpg)

In this scenario, we can see how on tap of initial text the editable text field is getting displayed and we can able to edit the text.

So let’s start with the process:

First, we have to initialize the variables.

```
bool _isEditingText = false;
TextEditingController _editingController;
String initialText = "Initial Text";
```

1. _isEditingText is the boolean variable and we have to set it false because we have to make it true when the user is tap on text.
2. TextEditingController -whenever a user modifies a text field with an associated TextEditingController, the text field edits and the controller notifies the listener. Listeners can then read the text and selection properties that the user has typed and updated. Basically the text editing controller is used to get the updated value from the text field.
3. initialText -Initial value, set to the text.

When we use any type of controller then we have to initialize and dispose of the controller.

So first initialize the controller in init state.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _editingController = TextEditingController(text: initialText);
}
@override
void dispose() {
  _editingController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

‘dispose()’ is called when the State object is removed, which is permanent.

This method is used to unsubscribe and cancel all animations, streams, etc.

The framework calls this method when this state object will never build again.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("'Editable Text"),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: _editTitleTextField(),
    ),
  );
}
```

In build widget, I am simply displaying a widget _editTitleTextField().

```
Widget _editTitleTextField() {
  if (_isEditingText)
    return Center(
      child: TextField(
        onSubmitted: (newValue){
          setState(() {
            initialText = newValue;
            _isEditingText =false;
          });
        },
        autofocus: true,
        controller: _editingController,
      ),
    );
  return InkWell(
    onTap: () {
      setState(() {
        _isEditingText = true;
      });
    },
    child: Text(
  initialText,
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.black,
    fontSize: 18.0,
  ),
 );
}
```

so what exactly the _editTitleTextField() widget does is, if the value of _isEditingText is false then simply show the text and on tap of text set the value of _isEditingText to true.

When _isEditingText is true then _editTitleTextField return text field. Textfield has parameter onSubmitted, so in onSubmitted method new value is assigned to initialText which is the updated value getting from _editingController.

Tada! This way we make the text editable and update the value of the text!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by having a `StatefulWidget` that keeps track of the state, by using a boolean for example. Let's say this bool is named `editing`. When `editing == false` you display a `Text` widget with the text to display, wrapped within a handler for the tap, such as a `GestureDetector`. When the user taps, the state is changed to `editing = true`. In this state you'll display a `TextField` with this value. You can use a `TextEditingController` within in this `StatefulWidget` and update its value there. This would allow you to up have all text selected when the user taps and changes to the editing state